# CSS3 property transition does not work on hover

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to do a hover on a div, which bold the border. I use the `box-shadow: inset...` property, because of that it does not expand my elements. However, the `transition` does not work and this is probably due to the fact that in the main class, the `box-shadow` does not have the `inset` property. I have no idea how to solve it...

```css
.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2.5rem 0 rgba(207, 212, 225, 0.4);
}

.card--group {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.card--group:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.1875rem #54d1bd;
}
```

```html
<div class="card card--group">

</div>
```

Comment: Please, in future, post your [mcve] code *in your question*, don't expect us to go look at it elsewhere. This is to guard against link-rot and reorganisation of external sites.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 2 different shadows, you can consider multiple `box-shadow` and you will be able to have a transition between each one. You show the inset one and you hide the intial one.

```css
.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 0 0 0 #54d1bd,
    0 0 2.5rem 0 rgba(207, 212, 225, 0.8);
}

.card--group {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.card--group:hover {
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 0 0 0.1875rem #54d1bd,
    0 0 0 0 rgba(207, 212, 225, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="card card--group">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a attribute in hover for .card--group:hover

```css
.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2.5rem 0 rgba(207, 212, 225, 0.4);
}

.card--group {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.card--group:hover {
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.1875rem #54d1bd;
}
```

```html
<div class="card card--group">

</div>
```